# Ignoring a global variable in JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have a global variable called `Filters` that is loaded before anything else, but JSHint tells me it's undefined in all files that use `Filters`. Of course, JSHint does not know the loading order (and yes, the order is enforced), so how would it know?

I tried adding it to the globals:

```
"globals": {
  "Filters": false
}
```

And that had no effect, so I tried:

```
"predef": [ "Filters" ]
```

Again, no effect.

These are also present:

```
"undef"         : true,
"latedef"       : false,
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I would normally just put the following at the top of my files:

```
/* globals Filters */
```

I prefer to specify globals on a per file basis.

Comment: Thing is, we got a massive amount of files and if the Filters class ever changes name.... May God have mercy on our poor souls =-/

Comment: According to the docs (http://jshint.com/docs/options/) globals is most useful when used in conjunction with undef.

Have you tried using the two together?

Comment: Not tried them together because (as far as I know) `globals` is what's going to replace `predef`. Will try it. Edit: tried, didn't work ;(